# GeoDjango and Google Maps

Tags: distance, geodjango

I try to calculate distance between two cities and I'm in big confusion because the results are wrong.

I have a model in geodjango like this:

```
class Address(geo_models.Model):
    coordinates = geo_models.PointField(srid=2180)
    objects = geo_models.GeoManager()
```

I create `Address` object using `Lat` anf `Lng` from **Google Maps** i this way

```
a = Address(coordinate = "POINT(%f %f)" % (lat, lng))
a.save()
```

and then I calculate distance between `Address` object and another point (which `lat` and `lng` I have also from Google Maps)

```
coordinates = fromstr("POINT(%f %f)" % (lat, lng), srid=2180)
for a in addresses.distance(coordinates):
    print(a.distance)
```

The calculation result is 25 km but I know that it is wrong. Right distance is around 18 km also Google Maps tells that it is 18 km.

Could someone tell me where I make a mistake?

**EDIT 01**:

I've added `srid=2180` to model and to reference point and now the result is `0.237103265743 m`

Answer (score 1):

This is likely a spatial projection issue. From the [GeoDjango (Django) documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/db-api/#distance-queries):

> Distance calculations with spatial data is tricky because, unfortunately, the Earth is not flat. Some distance queries with fields in a geographic coordinate system may have to be expressed differently because of limitations in PostGIS. Please see the [Selecting an SRID](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/model-api/#selecting-an-srid) section in the [GeoDjango Model API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/model-api/) documentation for more details.

Comment: I've edited my question. Could you look at?